# How to dismiss an OS X modal sheet with *either* ENTER or ESC key

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

My application launches a modal sheet that has several buttons. One of them is the default button (key equivalent \r) and pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key on the keyboard dismisses the sheet, as expected. I would like to have the same effect to also be achieved if the user presses the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. So *either* <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> should be the key equivalent for the button. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`-[NSResponder cancelOperation:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/cancelOperation:), which is automatically bound to the escape key:

> This method is bound to the Escape and Command-. (period) keys. The key window first searches the view hierarchy for a view whose key equivalent is Escape or Command-., whichever was entered. If none of these views handles the key equivalent, the window sends a default action message of cancelOperation: to the first responder and from there the message travels up the responder chain.

In other words, you can handle the escape key by implementing `-cancelOperation:` somewhere in your app's responder chain, such as the window controller.

Comment: No way to set this up in IB (without writing code) then?

Comment: @MichaelTeper You have to write code.  Buy if you wanted a reusable solution for IB you could subclass NSButton and override `-performKeyEquivalent:` to handle both Return and Escape.  http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/33066-nsbutton-and-multiple-key-equivalents.html